# Power categories in ASIC design (Design Compiler)

Tags: power, power-electronics, synthesis, asic, chip-design

I am currently working on the synthesis, with Synopsys' Design Compiler, of an AES encryption module.
In the power reports there are three power categories specified :

- Switching Power
- Internal Power
- Leakage Power

I understand what is the **Leakage Power** but I can not find out the differences between **Internal** and **Switching** power.

Can anybody explain me what are the differences between these two categories?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Switching power:
- The power needed to charge and discharge the capacitance of the gate during activity.  It will roughly scale with frequency. This includes the "shoot through" current.

Internal power:
- power that is consumed by circuits that have bias circuits or that discharge , for example- dynamic elements (which is separate from leakage power even if it is similar in nature).
- This also includes IR drops from power rail routing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you have any resources about that?

Answer (score 1):

Because I cannot comment (need 50 reputation or some nonsense), here's the [source](http://archive.eclass.uth.gr/eclass/modules/document/file.php/MHX303/Documentation/pwcug.pdf) for placeholder's response which Krouitch asked for.